# Не создается пользователь в БД Identity

Tags: asp-net-core-mvc

Все сделал по примеру из учебника.

1. Контекст БД

[image: Создается статический метод в контексте БД, по предварительному созданию пользователя]

2. Вызывается в Startup.cs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему в БД пользователь не создается. 
Никаких ошибок не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял свой косяк.

Забыл, что надо валидный пароль прописывать, пример : "Qwerty123$", или изменить правила валидности, тогда можно будет любой пароль прописывать